# How can I copy a directory if its contents have changed in CMake?

Tags: macos, copy, cmake

I'm looking for a way to copy a directory if the content of it is different as the destination. There is this copy_if_different option, but its only for a file. I am looking for a recursive way.

This is my code so far:

```
add_custom_command(
  TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME}
  POST_BUILD
  COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND}
  ARGS -E copy_directory "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/../folderA" "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/release/Debug/${PROJECT_NAME}.app/Contents/"
  COMMENT "Copying Bundle Stuff"
)
```

A unix system "only" solution would be okay, because I run this on OSX.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For OS X you can use the built-in command `rsync` instead:

```
ADD_CUSTOM_COMMAND(
   TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME}
   POST_BUILD
   COMMAND rsync
   ARGS -r
      "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/../folderA/"
      "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/release/Debug/${PROJECT_NAME}.app/Contents/"
   COMMENT "Copying Bundle Stuff")
```

Also see the [rsync documentation](https://rsync.samba.org/documentation.html).

Comment: Visual Studio 2019 has rsync in its Linux support tools too

Comment: any cross-platform solution?

Comment: https://bravenewmethod.com/2017/06/18/update_directory-command-for-cmake/

Comment: @sakra  FYI, I found that extremely slow.    A better option might be to wrap rsync or xcopy, depending on the platform.

Comment: An alternative can be "-E create_symlink".

Answer (score 1):

CMake v3.26-rc3 has a new [`cmake -E copy_if_different <dir>... <destination>`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#cmdoption-cmake-E-arg-copy_directory_if_different) command:

> *New in version 3.26.*
>
> Copy changed content of `<dir>...` directories to `<destination>` directory. If `<destination>` directory does not exist it will be created.
>
> `copy_directory_if_different` does follow symlinks. The command fails when the source directory does not exist.

Which you should be able to easily adapt from what you already have:

```
add_custom_command(
  TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME}
  POST_BUILD
  COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND}
  ARGS -E copy_directory_if_different "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/../folderA" "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/release/Debug/${PROJECT_NAME}.app/Contents/"
  COMMENT "Copying Bundle Stuff"
)
```

I'm also not sure what that `/release/Debug` is in there, but you might want to look at [the `$<CONFIG>` generator expression](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html#genex:CONFIG).